# Problems with image tag when using CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, uploadcare

I'm using [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com/) for uploading and storing images, which is working.

However, it appears CKEditor 4.1.1 is choking on these images.

**Adding an image via CKEditor.**

The initial placement of the image is as expected. However, when the data is saved, CKEditor is clearly doing something weird, prior to committing the data.

In several tests, during the formatting and rearrangement of the HTML, CKEditor is stripping out the "style" image attribute and the first opening double quote, which I can see in the text data on the database itself.

This behavior is entirely reproducible.

**Editing an image via CKEditor.**

Initially, the image looks fine. But when I view the source, the HTML for the image is sanitized to render as text, and not to render as an image object.

**Disabling 3rd party Plugins.**

As mentioned previously, I'm using Uploadcare, in addition to Word Count & Char Count. I disabled both Plugins, but this didn't change anything.

**Thoughts.**

During the saving process, I merely cleanse the data via the $this->db->escape() function in CodeIgniter, which cannot to circumvented, or the data won't commit and I receive an error.

Just to be clear, during testing, the errors occured with any type of image object; either added manually, or via Uploadcare.

In my view page, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('note', {
        allowedContent: true
    });
</script>
```

Which — [according to the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent) — "will disable the filter (data will not be filtered, all features will be activated)."

However, it doesn't work and it's doing exactly the same as before; stripping out the style attribute by name and converting the HTML to their regular textual equivalents.

If I chose to define something specifically, that turns almost everything off, including the plugins, and — strangely enough — the very thing I've written a rule for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('note', {
        allowedContent: {
            'img': {
                styles: 'height, width'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

So I have no idea what's going on.

I've also tried the advice in [a thread on their forums where someone is experiencing exactly the same problem](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Stop-CKEditor-converting-quotes) as me, but neither methods work, which leads me to believe this is a problem particular to the CKEditor itself, and not the treatment of data in and of itself.

If anyone has any advice as to how I can coax CKEditor into handing images, I'd be happy for any advice.

Comment: You should make your question shorter. Don't tell the full story - just list the facts and ask your question.

Comment: It appears that the weirdness I'm experiencing only happens if I make an edit to the document onto which the CKEditor is attached. Other than that, the image code remains fine.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? I have the exact same issue and neither of the suggested fixes work. I've confirmed it's not CodeIgniter related (I've tested with protect_identifiers disabled). CKEditor is somehow busting this in the post data before I get a chance to process it.

Comment: Correction, this IS CodeIgniter. Somewhere it's messing with even the $_POST variable (I'd assumed it would only if you used the input helper). A standalone HTML page shows this working fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Setting `allowedContent: true` for 99.9% would stop CKEditor from stripping images **if you did that correctly**.
2. Your `allowedContent` setting (2nd code sample) is incorrect. It does not allow `src` and `alt` attributes. Image without `src` will be stripped by CKEditor as invalid. So you should have at least:

   ```
   allowedContent: {
       img: {
          attributes: '!src, alt', // src is required
          styles: 'height, width'
       }
   }
   ```
3. So point 1. or 2. should work - I did that a lot of times, so I'm pretty sure of that. Thus, I think that you have a 2nd issue with your server breaking something.

Comment: Hi Reinmar, I've tried a number of things to cut the server and the framework out of the equation, and it makes no difference. As I explained, the style attribute name is being selectively removed, which neither the framework nor the database are doing.

Comment: I just tried your code and it makes no difference; CKEditor is still selectively removing the style attribute name.

Comment: Could you try to create a limited sample on JSFiddle?

Comment: No, it's much too complex. Based on another test, it appears that CodeIgniter might be the culprit for the removal of the attributes "style", and "height" when using regular height and width definitions which I've never seen before. And this happens even if I remove the xss_clean rule. But this does not explain why the HTML is being turned into textual items. So there's at least two different errors happening.

Comment: Making it less complex is the best way to debug it. As I wrote in point 3. - you're most likely dealing with more than one issue.

Comment: It's simple enough here, but too complex as a whole to transplant somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (on top of needing allowedContent: true or properly set up rules) is CodeIgniter's XSS filtering. Before we get access to $_POST (or $_GET/$_REQUEST) CI has already ran filtering over this data and in this case ruined it. This setting can't be overridden on a per-controller basis as it's already run before the controller is loaded.

So you can either disable it altogether in **/application/config/config.php** (not recommended)

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Or a less heavy handed approach (but still not ideal) manually disabling it  on certain pages (i.e. my example turning it off on all pages under /admin/help). Also in **/application/config/config.php**.

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

# Override the XSS filtering on /admin/help
if (preg_match("/^\/admin\/help/", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])) {
    $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
}
```

I had the exact issues you were having, and this has solved the issue for me.